# Finding out which device is using my network

Tags: wireless-networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

I have an open WiFi network in my business and it's recently slowed to a crawl. I'd like to find out which IP is using my bandwidth so I can block their MAC address.

My router doesn't support any sort of reporting, so I'd have to do this from  a connected Windows machine. What I'd really like is to be able to leave a program like Wireshark to record for a few hours, then be able to see a graph of which IP used how much bandwidth.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is open wifi, you should be able to sniff the traffic with any machine that has a wireless card and a sniffer installed (such as wireshark). Choose the wireless interface in wireshark and watch the packets come in.

Comment: I think I am able to sniff the traffic with Wireshark. The question is - once I've sniffed the traffic, and I have the packet logs from e.g. an entire day, how do I use Wireshark to show me which IP (or better yet, MAC address) is using my bandwidth?

Comment: You can sort captured packets by IP address. At that point you could see the total amount of data transferred by that address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that if and when the bandwidth-stealing guy ever returns. He just stopped a couple of days later, so I didn't have to ban anyone.